# How to manually fill a PagedList, from the SUBSET of rows in the current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I computed a bunch of rows myself manually, including some **additional data which isn't in my database**. For efficiency, I only computed the rows that are in the current page based on the page number and page size.

I tried to shove this into a `PagedList` but this requires the WHOLE set of data and not **just the subset I want to display**.

Please provide a full example of a custom paged list object that contains only the current page. Maybe implementing `IPagedList` directly??

Another issue is that I may not be able to know the total number of rows before I compute the whole list. Is this really necessary?

Comment: It depends to the implementation of `IPagedList`. In my point of view, `PagedList` is just a model (or view model) like other models. You can initialize it by setting its properties.

Comment: Also always the paged list contains just the page which you want to show. It never will contain the whole data.

Comment: In the end I had to compute the total number of rows to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the implementation of `IPagedList`. `PagedList` is just a model (or view model) like other models. You can initialize it by setting its properties. Also always the paged list contains just the page which you want to show. It never will contain the whole data.

**Note:** Implementations in this answer is just to keep things simple. To see a popular implemetation of paged list, you can take a look at [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList). It contains some implementations for both automatic and manual paging and also some useful helpers for ASP.NET MVC.

**Example**

Suppose we have such implementation of `IPagedList`:

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; set; }
    int PageSize { get; set; }
    int PageNumber { get; set; }
    int TotalItemsCount { get; set; }
}

public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
    where T : class
{
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can instantiate an instance of `PagedList<T>` like any other normal classes by assigning its properties.

Also you can create some extension methods to help you extract data of a specific page of an `IQueryable<T>` or an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
        int pageNumber, int pageSize) where T : class
    { return source.AsQueryable().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize); }
    public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
        int pageNumber, int pageSize) where T : class
    { return CreatePagesList<T>(source, pageNumber, pageSize); }
    private static PagedList<T> CreatePagesList<T>(IQueryable<T> source, 
        int pageNumber, int pageSize) where T : class
    {
        var items = new List<T>();
        var pageIndex = pageNumber - 1;
        if (source == null) source = new List<T>().AsQueryable();
        var totalItemsCount = source.Count();
        if (pageNumber < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageNumber cannot be less than 1.");
        if (pageSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageSize cannot be less than 1.");
        var pageCount = 0;
        if (totalItemsCount > 0)
            pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalItemsCount / (double)pageSize);
        if (pageIndex >= pageCount)
            pageIndex = Math.Max(pageCount - 1, 0);
        if (pageIndex < pageCount && totalItemsCount > 0)
            items.AddRange(source.Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
        var pagedList=  new PagedList<T>()
        {
            PageNumber = pageNumber, PageSize = pageSize,
            PageCount = pageCount, TotalItemsCount = totalItemsCount
        };
        pagedList.AddRange(items);
        return pagedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both your answer and @Kaspars Ozols' answer does what I need. I will go with yours because you were first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) as mentioned in answer implementations in this answer is just to keep things simple. To see a popular implemetation of paged list, you can take a look at [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList).

Answer (score 4):

For this task I suggest to use existing NuGet packages like this:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList

In this particular library you can generate subset of elements you want to display and create `StaticPagedList` from that list.

Here is a sample:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1; //MembershipProvider expects a 0 for the first page
        var pageSize = 10;
        int totalUserCount; // will be set by call to GetAllUsers due to _out_ paramter :-|

        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalUserCount);
        var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<MembershipUser>(users, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalUserCount);

        ViewBag.OnePageOfUsers = usersAsIPagedList;
        return View();
    }
}
```

See source code & other examples here: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: The library is maintained under [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList) as I also mentioned in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40558159/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out, I have been using PagedList by TroyGoode for a while and for some time have not visited project site therefore info about it not being maintained has slipped by.

Comment: Both your answer and @RezaAghaei's answer do what I need. I can only vote for one winning answer... I will go with his because he was first.